# Brew not installing pygtk properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, pygtk

First let me start by giving an example of what happens when I install numpy using HomeBrew

```
brew install numpy
```

This successfully dowloads and pours. And now when I try to import in python it works properly.

```
>>>import numpy
>>>
```

Now I try to install pygtk through HomeBrew using

```
brew install pygtk
```

It successfully Downloads and pours. But when I import it in python I get

```
>>>import pygtk
Import Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
>>>
```

Now I went and checked my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
numpy exists but pygtk does not. But pygtk exists in /usr/local/lib/
Why is brew doing this? Also am I getting something fundamentally wrong here?
Now I really don't know what to do exactly but I don't think copying pygtk from /usr/local/lib/ to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Note: I am using MAC OS and I mainly work through the terminal and would prefer a solution through terminal itself.

Edit1: I have found a solution or rather a workaround.
Basically I am downloading the latest PyGTK.pkg and then installing it. And then copying all the files in the system default python to my python2.7

```
wget -P /Users/mac_test/Downloads/ https://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/PyGTK/2.24.0/PyGTK.pkg
installer -pkg /Users/mac_test/Downloads/PyGTK.pkg -target /
cp -r /opt/gtk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Not sure this is the best way though.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you prefer brew over pip and virtualenv?

Answer (score -1):

How it worked for me:
First of all I have python installed via brew:

```
which python && python --version
/usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.13
```

Then I installed pygtk through `brew install pygtk` and it was successful

After that:

```
python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygtk
>>> help(pygtk)
```

It responds with this:

```
Help on module pygtk:

NAME
    pygtk

FILE
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygtk.py
```

So probably copy pygtk to site-packages might solve your issue.

I don't know specific reason you prefer brew over pip + virtualenv but I gently recommend you to try it instead of brew and global library installation.

Comment: pip couldn't install pygtk. And I still didn't go through virtualenv but I am basically writing a script that will do changes so that other applications using python can use those packages, so am not totally sure whether packages installed on virtualenv are accessible.

Comment: Also copying of the pygtk folder to site-packages didn't help